# Website homepage not executing callback without ?#

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have setup a website hosted on AWS S3. My home file is setup in the home directory as index.html and when I open the website, it opens with that file which is exactly what I want. When I go to my site (mysite.io), it is loaded to mysite.io which is also what I want. The issue that I am having is that a callback function that I have is not being executed if "/?#" is not in the URL.

As can be seen in the code below, when a user inputs their data in the login form, the phone and password is read in and passed into the authenticateUser method. If there is no "/?#" in the URL, the cognitoUser.authenticateUser(...) does not execute as is denoted by the logs below.

```
$('#login-form').submit(function () {
    var phone = $('#login-phone').val();
    var password = $('#login-pass').val();
    authenticateUser(phone, password);
});

function authenticateUser(username, password) {
  // a bunch of variables created here
  console.log("This is always executed");

  myVariable.doSomething(someStuff, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
      console.log("This is not executed if there is no '?#' after mysite.io/");
    },
    onFailure: function (err) {
      alert("Neither is this");
    }

  });

  console.log("This is also always executed");
}
```

I can't find anything about this error online and would really appreciate some help as I am pretty new to webdev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are submitting the form, so the page reloads. Use `event.preventDefault()` at the bottom of your submit Event handling function. Of course you have to pass the `event` Object into the parameter:

```
$('#login-form').submit(function(ev){
  authenticateUser($('#login-phone').val(), $('#login-pass').val());
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thank you; that worked! So do I want to have that `event.preventDefault()`  on every one of my form submissions since I don't really want the page to reload on form submission? When would you want the page to reload?

Comment: Yes, if you are using AJAX, which should always be the case these days, then use `event.preventDefault()`. Oh, HTML `<form>`s use their `action` attribute to send code via their `method` attribute, during normal (old school) submission, meaning any Server Code (usually PHP) code would be executed based on the `action` attribute. If left out the page submits to itself. You would not want to use old school form submission unless you want a guaranteed page redirect. Usually, you run tests that produce errors if something goes wrong, so redirects should happen after submission.